# iframe overflows div on iOS

Tags: ios, css, iframe

I have the following set up:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="module-texture">
        <div class="module-inner">
            <iframe>yadayadayada</iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `iframe` is set to `height:300px` and `.module-inner` has an `overflow:auto`. Additionally, the surrounding div `#main` has a height set as well. When viewing on my iPhone, the `iframe` still overflows `#main`.

What can be causing the `iframe` to overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would fix it

```
#main overflow:hidden;
```